# Dictionary keys and values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working with Python dictionaries and there's something I don't understand when I use the function `dict.values()` and `dict.keys()`.

Why do they give as a result also the "description" of the function? Am I missing something here?

```
participant = {"name": "Lisa", "age": 16, "activities": [{"name": "running", "duration": 340},{"name": "walking", "duration": 790}]}
print(participant.values())
print(participant.keys())
```

The print gives these results:

```
dict_values([[{'duration': 340, 'name': 'running'}, {'duration': 790, 'name': 'walking'}], 'Lisa', 16])
dict_keys(['activities', 'name', 'age'])
```

I don't want `'dict_values'` and `'dict_keys'` in the result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong - in 3.x, those methods return *views* for various performance reasons. See https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists

Comment: If you add a `*`, e.g. `print(*partici...`, it'll print more tidily.

Comment: I had to use list..missed the python updates! thanks

Comment: It's not so much a description of the function (or to be more accurate, the method); rather, it's the _type_ of the view object that the method returns. (As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) explain, view objects are related to sets).

Comment: (cont)  Being able to see the exact type of a view (or other object) can be convenient in the Python shell or when developing, but it's not expected that such strings will ever be shown to the user: they are for the benefit of programmers. You should use proper formatting techniques to display the contents of containers to the the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you can use keyword `list`:

```
list(participant.keys()) # ['name', 'activities', 'age']
list(participant.values())
# ['Lisa', [{'name': 'running', 'duration': 340}, {'name': 'walking', 'duration': 790}], 16]
```